# My php code is not working in Linux Centos 6 while its working in windows

Tags: php, linux, centos

```
<?php
ini_set('include_path', '/AmazonPHP2/aws/aws-autoloader.php');
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\Ec2\Exception\Ec2Exception;
#ini_set('include_path', '/aws/aws-autoloader.php');
#ini_set('include_path', '/aws/Aws/Common/Aws');
#ini_set('include_path', '/aws/Aws/Ec2/Exception/Ec2Exception');
$aws = Aws::factory('/aws/Credentials.php');
$ec2Client = $aws->get('Ec2');
 try
 { 
//Create the key pair
$keyPairName = 'my-keypair';
$result = $ec2Client->createKeyPair(array(
   'KeyName' => $keyPairName));
print "<b>---- Key Successfully Created ---- <b> " . PHP_EOL;
}
 catch (Ec2Exception $e)
    {
print "<b>---- Key cannot be generated ---- <b> " . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

When I am executing this code I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Aws\Common\Aws' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/AmazonPOC/Key.php on line 8
```

AmazonPHP2 contains a folder aws that contains classes that are to be used, but here it is giving me fatal error, however, the code is working fine in windows.

Thanks

Comment: I faced similar problem too, mine was include('/scripts/path-to-my-php'), it could work on windows but somehow did not work on centos with lampp installed... the script that calls the include was in '/website/myscript.php', same Not Found error. I still have not found out why, very perplexing

Comment: Please note : Windows filepaths/filenames are case insensitive where in linux Foo != foo